# Как получить фото присланный пользователем боту в Telegram на java? Используя GetFile

Tags: java, telegram-bot, spring

```
package ru.bozhov.dormitory.botAPI;

import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.experimental.FieldDefaults;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.DefaultBotOptions;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramWebhookBot;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.BotApiMethod;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.GetFile;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.send.SendMessage;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.Document;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.File;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.PhotoSize;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.Update;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiException;
import ru.bozhov.dormitory.botAPI.facade.TelegramFacade;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.channels.Channels;
import java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel;
import java.util.List;

@Data
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@Slf4j
public class DormitoryBot extends TelegramWebhookBot {
    private String botPath;
    private String botName;
    private String botToken;
    private TelegramFacade telegramFacade;

    public DormitoryBot(TelegramFacade telegramFacade){
        this.telegramFacade = telegramFacade;
    }
    @Override
    public BotApiMethod<?> onWebhookUpdateReceived(Update update) {
        if(update.hasMessage() &&(update.getMessage().hasPhoto() ||update.getMessage().hasDocument())){
            List<PhotoSize> photoSizeList = update.getMessage().getPhoto();
            for(PhotoSize photoSize : photoSizeList){
                try {
                    uploadFile(photoSize.getFileId());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    log.error(String.valueOf(e));
                }
            }
        }

        return telegramFacade.handleMessage(update);
    }
    public void uploadFile(String fileId) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL("https://api.telegram.org/bot"+botToken+"/getFile?file_id="+fileId);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( url.openStream()));
        String res = in.readLine();
        JSONObject jresult = new JSONObject(res);
        JSONObject path = jresult.getJSONObject("result");
        String file_path = path.getString("file_path");
        URL download = new URL("https://api.telegram.org/file/bot" + botToken + "/" + file_path);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("upload/" + fileId);
        System.out.println("Start upload");
        ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(download.openStream());
        fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
        fos.close();
        rbc.close();
        System.out.println("Uploaded!");
    }
    @Override
    public String getBotPath() {
        return botPath;
    }
    @Override
    public String getBotUsername() {
        return botName;
    }
}
```